# how to use stub in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following snippet of code

```
def index
    session[:previous_url] = request.referer 

   if session[:previous_url].blank?
     redirect_to registration_path(id: current_user.associate_username)
   end 
end
```

and I am writing a test for it 
Test:

```
describe 'index' do
  it 'renders the index page' do
    controller.stub(current_user: FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user))
    session = {}
    session[:previous_url] = 'http://example.com/new'
    get :index, params, session
    expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

This does not allow me get passed the `blank?`. Does anybody know any other way I can get past the `blank?` to return `false` and thus not redirect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could assign `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` in your `before` block. Like so:

```
  before do
    request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "http://localhost:3000/"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
describe 'index' do
  it 'renders the index page' do
    controller.stub(current_user: FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user),
                    session: {previous_url: "http://example.com/new"})
    get :index, params, session
    expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
end
```